Is it possible to implement a constexpr static_vector?
Is it possible to implement a constexpr static_vector?
By static_vector, I mean a vector which has its storage space inside the vector (not heap allocated) and it cannot grow beyond the compile-time CAPACITY. Something like this:
template <typename T, int CAPACITY>
struct static_vector {
    unsigned char data[sizeof(T)*CAPACITY];
    int size = 0;

    template <typename ...PARAMETERS>
    constexpr void emplace_back(PARAMETERS &&...parameters) {
        new(data + size * sizeof(T)) T(std::forward<PARAMETERS>(parameters)...);
        size++;
    }

    constexpr const T &operator[](int idx) const {
        return std::launder(reinterpret_cast<const T *>(data))[idx];
    }
};

(hopefully this implementation is UB-free).
If I try to use this implementation, I get various constexpr-related errors. Here is a little test program (godbolt):
struct Foo {
    int x;

    constexpr Foo(int x) : x(x) { }
};

constexpr int fn() {
    static_vector<Foo, 3> a;
    a.emplace_back(1);
    a.emplace_back(2);
    return a[0].x + a[1].x;
}

int main() {
    constexpr int v = fn();
    printf("%d\n", v);
}

As far as I know, it is possible to do this if heap allocated storage is used. The question is, is it possible to do this using an "embedded" space, like static_vector does? I know that this is not possible with older standards, but are we going to have something in the next standard which makes this possible?
(I also tried to implement this using a union, but it fails in a different way)

std::inplace_vector

@NathanOliver: thanks, I didn't know about this. I think this quote answers my question: "If N > 0 and std::is_trivial_v is false, then member functions of inplace_vector are not usable in constant expressions.".

If someone else is interested, this is the proposal: https://wg21.link/P0843

One current (in 2024) disadvantage of std::inplace_vector is that it is proposed for C++26.   So, most current implementations do not support it, and there is still potential that it will not make it into the standard.

There are various similar solutions like boost::container::static_vector, boost::container::small_vector, llvm::SmallVector, folly::small_vector, eastl::fixed_vector although I haven't check if any of them can be constexpr

@Peter If you can live with it only working for objects with default constructor then inherit std:array. Then you only have to override or add a few methods to work in the difference between used size and maximum capacity. Or, you know, just copy in an implementation of std::incplace_vector for compilers that don't have it (yet).

@Peter It's already in the standard.

@Barry  C++26 is a working draft (version N4981, IIRC) not a standard.

@Peter For all intents and purposes, it's the standard. You're making it seem like it's still just a proposal. It was already adopted into the working draft. For it to not make it into C++26, it would need to be actively removed - which exceedingly given the unanimous consensus with which it was adopted.

@Barry - And you're portraying it as more advanced in the standardisation process than it is (I guess, from your answer, because YOU proposed and champion related aspects).  Anyone who takes an interest in evolution of the standard will know that proposals get voted on, introduced into drafts, then may evolve substantially [or be removed entirely] before finding their way into a ratified standard.  Not every developer can afford to rely on a language/library feature when it is not yet in a ratified standard - which is the current status here.

@Peter Rather than suggesting that I'm being dishonest in my portrayal (I am not) due to nefarious ulterior motives (which makes no sense anyway), you could have simply checked whether my name is on the proposal. It is not.

@Barry - I wasn't suggesting you were being dishonest.   You said "it's already in the standard" whereas the actual status is that it is in a draft.   I consider that your claim m that being in a draft is "for all intents and purposes the standard" is incorrect and misleading, given that not everyone can afford to adopt things from draft standards into active development.   It's one thing to be interested in how the standard evolves - it's another thing to be able to apply new features as soon as they are introduced into a draft.


Is it possible to implement a constexpr static_vector?

As of what's in the language for C++26 so far, not completely no.
You need to provide storage for the backing array, and you need to be able to construct and retrieve objects from there. What are our options?
We could use an array of unsigned char:
alignas(T) unsigned char a1[sizeof(T[N])];

But this requires reinterpret_cast to get an object back out, and we can't reinterpret_cast at compile time.
We could directly construct an array:
T a2[N];

But this requires us to actually construct N objects. You definitely do not want to do that if T isn't trivially default constructible — because initially you want your vector to be empty. It doesn't matter here if we use T[N] or std::array<T, N>, although the latter just directly supports N == 0.
We could stash our array in a union:
union { T a3[N]; };

The problem with a3 is that the only way to actually start the lifetime of a3 and use the array like an array is... to construct the whole array. Which has the same problem as a2 again. And if we don't start the lifetime of a3 then none of the array operations work.
Or we could try to do an array of a union:
union U { T val; };
U a4[N];

The problem with this is that you have APIs that return a T* that actually has to be a pointer to T that you can do pointer arithmetic on, not a T inside of a union.
That's why the current design for std::inplace_vector<T, N> contains this sentence:

For any N>0, if is_trivial_v<T> is false, then no inplace_vector<T, N> member functions are usable in constant expressions.

Because because if is_trivial_v<T> is true then constructing a2 is fine (that's the direct T[N] version) — no initialization happens, and now we have a proper array that all the compile time evaluation can deal with easily enough.

I have a proposal in flight that will hopefully land in C++26 that will allow the union solution to work for all T, by ensuring that the language starts the lifetime of a3 (the union { T[N] } version) without having to initialize the whole array. That will make it possible to have a completely constexpr static_vector, which is why that paper also strikes the sentence I cited earlier.

Thanks for this work! I skimmed through the versions, I'm not sure whether this option was considered... I've never understood why union U { std::string z; } doesn't work in the first place (I mean the def. ctor is deleted). Why does C++ want to initialize unions so hard? I use union for the purpose of postponing the initialization. In this case, the default ctor/dtor should be trivial instead of deleted. And we should have a mechanism to switch between active members, it is your std::start_lifetime idea. But I understand that this is inconsistent with some of the already existing rules.

Personally, I like the trivial union variant the best. But without the "first alternative's lifetime is started" special case. trivial union should mean that the def. ctor/dtor is always trivial. With the usual way we can make a member active. And in case we want to make an array member active, but without calling the ctor's of the array elements, we need std::start_lifetime.
